# Does the title tag have content?

Tags: html, tags, title

From my point of view, content has come to be defined as two separate things in HTML:

> 1) All of the information between the open and closed body tags that is visible on a webpage.
>
> 2) That which is visible on a webpage that is placed between *any* open and closed tags.

This may seem knit-picky, but it's important when teaching the concept of HTML content -- I believe in establishing and holding consistent definitions when teaching computer programming terminology.

Is number one correct? -- in which case the `<title>` would not have content. Or is number two correct? -- in which case `<title>` would have content.

Comment: Neither of your two definitions is correct. Even some things that aren't visible, like `alt` text on images, are content. Don't believe me? Ask a vision-impaired person who uses a screen reader. Like `alt` text, from a UX point of view `<title>` is absolutely content: Most users rely on it to switch tabs and identify bookmarks, and it's the most prominent thing shown in search engine results.

Comment: There wasn't really any need for the condescending undercurrent in the diction of your response. But regardless, thank you for informing me of the above, it was indeed fruitful information!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Content" in the context of HTML is not subjective. We are lucky enough to have [a spec which defines *everything*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/), so there's no "point of view" to be had. [The spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#content-models) clearly defines every element's *content model,* which is defined as ["A normative description of what content must be included as children and descendants of the element."](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-definitions)

> #### [3.2.4 Content models](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#content-models)
>
> Each element defined in this specification has a content model: a description of the element's expected [contents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#concept-html-contents). An [HTML element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#html-elements) must have contents that match the requirements described in the element's content model. The **contents** of an element are its children in the DOM, except for [`template`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-template-element) elements, where the children are those in the [template contents](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#template-contents) (a separate [`DocumentFragment`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#documentfragment) assigned to the element when the element is created).

---

[The spec dictates that the `<title>` element's content model is](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-title-element)

> #### Content model:
>
> [Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#text-content) that is not [inter-element whitespace.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#inter-element-whitespace)

Nothing more, and nothing less.

Comment: Thanks Matt! That was precisely the information I needed; sometimes programming vernacular gets a little jumbled and the words within it take on a much different, more generalized definition then the specific, technical definitions they originated from. I appreciate the direction and clarification!